# How to compare the data in two separate CSV files in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am very new to Python so would appreciate any help that I can get.

**Problem Statement**: Given two similar csv files, assert whether they are the same or not. If not, return the differences in each column. The assert condition should be checked for every column separately. The rows have a unique id. This id may/can not be sorted, Eg- the similar row with id=1 in csv1 might be the last row in csv2 with id=1.

**To Do**:

1. Iterate over rows in csv1
2. Find out that row's id and then find that id in csv2.
3. Now, compare the data of these two rows and return the differences for each column separately.

Please help me with a solution to this problem or how i should go about it.

**Update:**
Hi, thanks for the answers. I achieved my desired result through this:

```
def compare_column_name(expectedObj, resultObj, index):
    val_expected = expectedObj['column']
    val_result = (resultObj['column'].values[0])
    if((not val_expected) and (not val_result)):
        print("Null values")
    else:
        assert val_expected == val_result, (
            'column value discrepancy at index = ' + str(index))

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    Id = (row['id'])
    v = df2.loc[(df2['id'] == Id)]

    compare_column_name(row, v, index)
```

Comment: What have you done so far?  We can help debug code, but don't (normally) write code from scratch,  For a start, load the files, as lists, arrays or dataframes.

Answer (score -1):

You can compare 2 datasets via datacompy: https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import datacompy

data1 = """acct_id,dollar_amt,name,float_fld,date_fld
10000001234,123.45,George Maharis,14530.1555,2017-01-01
10000001235,0.45,Michael Bluth,1,2017-01-01
10000001236,1345,George Bluth,,2017-01-01
10000001237,123456,Bob Loblaw,345.12,2017-01-01
10000001239,1.05,Lucille Bluth,,2017-01-01
"""

data2 = """acct_id,dollar_amt,name,float_fld
10000001234,123.4,George Michael Bluth,14530.155
10000001235,0.45,Michael Bluth,
10000001236,1345,George Bluth,1
10000001237,123456,Robert Loblaw,345.12
10000001238,1.05,Loose Seal Bluth,111
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1))
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2))

compare = datacompy.Compare(
    df1,
    df2,
    join_columns='acct_id',  #You can also specify a list of columns
    )
compare.matches(ignore_extra_columns=False)
# False

# This method prints out a human-readable report summarizing and sampling differences
print(compare.report())
```

Answer (score -1):

It would have been better if you provided the dataframe.

Let's assume your dfs are `df` and `df_2`, and your row id is in the `id` column. You can compare the columns of the corresponding rows based on the `id` as:

```
df.apply(lambda x: df_2[df_2['id'] == x['id']].squeeze() == x, axis=1)
```